# Out of memory error or program unresponsive during multithreading JAVA

Tags: java, multithreading

I am new to multi threading. Literally. And I am pretty new to Java overall. HOwever, I am making a simulation and the thread seem to be working well except I occasionally have the program become unresponsive and once it said out of memory error. I assume this is because I am creating too many threads? At the point it normally does this I have over 2000 threads running at the same time. I can adjust the code (i.e reduce the number of customers or increase time between ticks) to release the pressure on the system but I am wondering if there is something I could be doing to help ease the burden within each thread itself. I'm pretty sure it isn't a deadlock since the code runs fine if I do the above but run it for longer so the same amount of customers come through. I will show the relevant parts of the code and if more is required I am happy to put this up. Please I don't understand this very well, so some very simple and helpful explanations would be greatly appreciated, since if the comment is too complex I probably wont' know how to implement it.

This is the main class that creates the thread.

```
    CheckoutFloor checkoutFloor = new CheckoutFloor();
    checkoutFloor.addCheckoutOperators(checkoutOperators);
    int tick = 0;
    int customers = 0;

    while (tick < simulationTime) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int random = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;
            if (random <= 50) {
                customerRunnable customer = new customerRunnable(checkoutFloor);
                Thread t = new Thread(customer);
                t.start();
                tick++;
            }
            else {
                tick++;
            }
```

Here is the runnable code:

```
 public void run() {
    try {
        customer.addRandomShopTime();
        while (customer.shopTime > 0) {
            Thread.sleep(1);
            customer.setShopTime();
        }
        CheckoutOperator checkoutOperator = checkoutFloor.weightedCheckoutDeterminator();
        checkoutOperator.addCustomer(customer);

        while (customer.checkoutTime > 0) {
            Thread.sleep(1);
            if (checkoutOperator.customerList.get(0) == customer) {
                customer.setCheckoutTime();
            }
        }
        checkoutOperator.removeCurrentCustomer();

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

    }
```

And here are the relevant methods.

```
public synchronized void addCustomer(Customer newCustomer) {
        customerList.add(newCustomer);
        System.out.println("no. of customers" + counter);
        counter++;
}


public synchronized CheckoutOperator weightedCheckoutDeterminator() {
    int totalCustomers = 0;
    int totalCustomersAdj = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < checkoutOpList.size(); i++) {
        totalCustomers += getCheckoutOperator(i).getCustomerListLength();
    }
    if (totalCustomers == 0) {
        return getCheckoutOperator(0);
    } else {
        totalCustomersAdj = (checkoutOpList.size() * totalCustomers) - totalCustomers;
        int randomNumber = 0;
        try {
            randomNumber = new Random().nextInt(totalCustomersAdj) + 1;
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            return checkoutOpList.get(0);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < checkoutOpList.size(); i++) {
            int operatorCustLength = (getCheckoutOperator(i).getCustomerListLength());

            if (randomNumber <= (totalCustomers - operatorCustLength)) {
                return getCheckoutOperator(i);

            } else {
                randomNumber = randomNumber - (totalCustomers - operatorCustLength);
            }
        }
        return checkoutOpList.get(0); //HOPEFULLY UNREACHABLE!!!

    }
```

I'm just wondering if, due to my lack of knowledge, there is anything I am missing that woudl help the flow a bit more and help it run faster?

[edit: I should add that under normal conditions I would never have 2000 threads running and this is me pushing the system to the max. I suspect that this IS the problem and I guess I am asking if there is something else I am missing due to my lack of knowledge. I just don't like the idea that if someone changes the code to make it more intensive that it might crash.].

Comment: "At the point it normally does this I have over 2000 threads running at the same time." OH GOD WHY

Comment: haha. Ok so THAT is the problem! I suspected so I guess I am putting this up to make sure that that is my problem, and not something else. I am really putting it through the ringer when I have the 2000 threads running and it would probably never ever be run for that many. But I just don't like the idea of it not been able to do that if someone changed the code or something?

Comment: Well, to be honest, I'm not sure if that's *the* problem. It's just something you should *never* do unless you actually have something on the order of 2000 processing units

Comment: @user3580294 Or if each thread is extremely I/O bound.

Comment: Just as a rule of thumb, you should never have more threads than available processing units. Does the OOM error happen when you limit the number of threads spawned?

Comment: I suspect it is because 2000 threads = 2000 customers. If I run the same program for longer, but under less intensive conditions, (ie there will never be 2000 threads running at the same time, but 2000 did come through and then exit the code) I don't get any stalls and so this suggests it isn't a deadlock or anything. Well I assume this to be true. I guess thats why I am asking.

Comment: Hmmm. I'd suggest that you use VisualVM or something to profile your code and see what's taking up most of the heap. I'm not sure exactly how expensive threads are -- I just know that that many threads is a big problem for your processor. Not sure how much that'll make your RAM hate life... But at least from what it sounds like it's the number of threads (or whatever's inside the threads) that's causing the problem.

Comment: I know what you are saying but this is for a assignment and a part of that is I HAVE to create the threads for each customer. i did explain to him that I didn't think this makes sense at all, but I think he just wants us to do it so we can learn from it etc.

Comment: I agree because I got that outofmemory error in one which suggests it' s my computer freaking out.

Comment: Hmmm... Try profiling your code. Perhaps it's whatever your threads are doing with data structures that's the problem and not the threads themselves. Profiling should reveal what's eating up most of your memory.

Comment: JVM can easily support 2k threads. Event 20k should not be a problem. Try to increase the value of heap to `1g` adding JVM argument Xmx like `java -Xmx1g  your app`

Comment: I am getting this - Profiler Agent Warning: NULL owner for lock 1632dfd4.